# How do I remove/close the JVM, because of memory usage, after reading a large xlsx file?

Tags: r, jvm, package, xlsx, rjava

I read a few large xlsx files into a data.frame in R using the package xlsx and the function read.xlsx2(). The files are about 10.000 rows and 140 columns. I increased the heap to 2 GB as the package uses the rJava package to read xlsx files. The problem is that after I have read one file and then keeps on working the memory is still being used by R. I often need to read several files and after reading two xlsx files I run out of memory again (java.lang.OutOfMemory...). How can I clear the memory after having read a file? After a lot of Google searches I believe it's because of the JVM that is initialized through rJava. The memory is cleared if I restart R (and I keep the data by saving the image).

I don't know anything about Java so I hope that someone can help me.

EDIT: I Use R 3.0.0 64 bit and java 64 bit and Windows 7 with 8 GB of ram. Just to clarify.. If I save the workspace and restart R, then the memory usage of the data looks very normal. I think (but I am not sure) the memory problem starts when the xlsx file is being unpacked. I know that I can still increase the heap size, but I would like to limit the memory usage so I don't need to install extra ram on all my computers. I have also used the xlConnect package and here the memory issue is the same.

/Kenneth

Comment: Those are small files by R standards. You need to specify what OS and machine resources you are using. Is the heap taking all of you available memory?

Comment: Did you try to use xlcFreeMemory with XLConnect?

Comment: For the record, I _always_ follow a call to `read.xlsx2` with `gc()` because of this issue. Increasing heap size, etc. has never helped me.